# how to serve plain js single page application on github pages?

Tags: javascript, github, single-page-application, github-pages

the website gives error 404 upon reload when it path except https://username.github.io/projname/
it does all routing to my paths using navbar links

```
const router=(hrf)=>{
    history.replaceState(null,null,hrf)
}

export default router
```

the function below is giving router paths

```
item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            document.querySelectorAll('.linkbtn').forEach(el=>{
                el.style.backgroundColor=''
            })
            document.getElementById('projectbtn').style=''
            e.preventDefault()
            router(e.target.parentElement.href)
            component(e.target.id.slice(0,-3))
            item.style.backgroundColor='#f2f2f2'

        })
```

i was expecting github to serve index.html with index.js to be served at all paths just
rest is handled by js

```
type here
```

Comment: Routing requires Server-Side configuration. The server has to route all requests to the single-page application so that the SPA can handle the request.

Comment: on development im using webpack-dev-server 
historyfallback:true 
and publicPath:/proj_todo_odin/

Comment: How is this related to your problem? I've described, why it's not possible to host a SPA with routing on GitHub pages.

Comment: can u show me how to do server side configuration on github i can create a basic nodejs app to serve my dist folder as intended with 
```
app.get(/^\/(?!api).*/, function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: You can't change the server configuration on GitHub